# Export/Import Events for diffrent JS Files

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, node-modules

I have a Index.js with all the Dependencies and resources which starts like this and is followed with all my functions and event listeners

```
//Index.js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const external = require("./extern")

const Database = require("@replit/database")

const db = new Database()
const client = new Discord.Client()

//code 

module.exports= {client};
```

now i want to have a EventListener that also uses the const "client" in another file called extern.js

edit:

```
//extern.js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = require('./index')

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})
```

what i found out so far:

i created a function hello() that prints hello world in the console in my extern.js
exported the function with "module.exports = hello
and in my index.js i got it working with

```
const hello = require ("./extern")
hello()
```

that works perfectly but as soon as i put

"const client = require("./index")"

in my extern.js i get the error with the message even when "client" isnt used in the file an the line got nothing to with the function

```
TypeError: hello is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Stechuhr/index.js:184:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Stechuhr/extern.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
```

btw im coding in repl.it

Comment: dependency injection,`module.exports = client => { client.on("ready", (... }`, then in main file `external(client)` after initializing client, or also abstract Discord stuff from main and then require it in extern.js

Comment: This seems like just a generic import/export implementation. Export `client` from one module and import it into another and then you can use the same `client` object in both files.

Comment: to get the returning value from require() you have to `module.exports` something, think of require as in, and module.exports as out. See some basic tutorials or here is fix https://replit.com/@lcherone/67496047: if you need to pass somthing to the constructor of something, then do like my prev comment `module.exports = config => new Discord.Client(config)` or for multi `module.exports = function(){ return new Discord.Client(...arguments)}` or do the construct in consumer `module.exports = Discord.Client`, then in consumer you can call the return `new (require('./client'))({foo:'bar'})`, in/out

Answer (score -1):

you should only export client:

```js
module.exports = client;
```

then only amount

Comment: i tried that already, module.exports = client; in my index.js and but the code snippet in extern.js isn't used.

```const Discord = require("discord.js")
var client = require('./index')

  // log for successfull connected bot
  client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
  })

```
how do i require that exactly in my extern.js

Comment: var client = require('./index.js') missing .js